# Freeware FTP client with batch processing support

Tags: software-rec, filesystems, ftp, batch

Is there a freeware FTP client with batch processing support?

I have 50 IP addresses that I need to upload to. How do I make this as simple as possible?

Comment: Which OS are you using? I would suggest a command line client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, [WinSCP has scripting functionality](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting). On other systems ([Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), [OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X), [AIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX)) you should be able to script your command-line (s)ftp client to do whatever you like.

Comment: Great thanks. This looks like a good place to start. Do you happen to know where i could find some script tutorials?