# How do I upload a file to an FTP server using a batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, ftp, batch-file

I have created a batch file called `FTP_automation.bat` which contains the code below.

```
SET MyPath=E\PGP\test_pg
ftp
open 142.245.30.165 21
TESTA9MS
test11
binary
put %MyPath%
quit
Pause
```

When I am running `FTP_automation.bat`, it's not uploading the file which I am passing the parameter.

The script stops after `ftp` which is mentioned in the batch file, and it's not connecting to the IP address and port number which I have passed in the batch file.

If I manually typed these commands it was working perfectly. What correction am I supposed to do to this code?

Comment: Here you go http://superuser.com/q/242763/300548

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put the `ftp` commands to a separate file. You cannot put lines you otherwise type on terminal to `.bat` file and expect it to behave identically. The `.bat` file can include only Windows commands. When you run the `ftp` command from the batch file, it waits for its commands. It does not know about the `.bat` file, so it cannot read the commands from there.

So put your commands to a separate text file (e.g. `ftp.txt`).

```
open 142.245.30.165 21
TESTA9MS
test11
binary
put E\PGP\test_pg
quit
```

And run it from the `.bat` file like:

```
ftp -s:ftp.txt
pause
```

If you really need to use a dynamic file name (from an environment variable), you need to create the text file on-the-fly. The `ftp` does not support variables.

---

If you use a better FTP client, you might be able to both have the commands in the batch file and use the environment variables.

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net):

```
set MyPath=E\PGP\test_pg

winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://TESTA9MS:test11@142.245.30.165" ^
    "put ""%MyPath%""" ^
    "exit"

pause
```

For an introduction to scripting with WinSCP see:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

There's also a guide to [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp). You can even have WinSCP GUI [generate the batch file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) for you.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*